# Soap API call to Magento failing to retrieve xml document

Tags: xml, api, magento, symfony, wsdl

I have a cron job that runs every hour to retrieve products that get added to my Magento shop.

Annoyingly it has stopped working and it is proving difficult to de-bug.

When it attempts to run I get the following error:

```
  [SoapFault]
  looks like we got no XML document
```

After doing some research, it looks like the xml being retured could contain errors and therefore not be valid hence the error.

Is there a way to see the retured xml?

The code has not changed, which makes me suspect it may be a setting in magento that has been changed by another user.

The cron job is built on a Symfony 2 platform.

Heres my code:

```
private $client;
private $session;

private $api = 'https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/api/?wsdl';
private $user = 'xxx';
private $pass = 'xxx';

$output->writeln('Updating shop product...');

$this->client = new \SoapClient($this->api);
$this->session = $this->client->login($this->user, $this->pass);

$products = $this->client->call($this->session, 'catalog_product.list');
```

Comment: Test the response to 'https://www.mywebsite.co.uk/api/?wsdl' ? I'd say the error  'we got no XML' means there is no XML file being returned. The docs offer alternative API call methods: http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/introduction.html

Comment: Also maybe look at outputting the last SOAP response. http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php

Comment: Annoyingly I cant do that because the script dies and returns the error on the $products = $this->client->call($this->session, 'catalog_product.list'); line, so anything after that line (i.e - last soap responce) will not be output

Answer (score 1):

use a debugging proxy like [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) ( Windows )  or [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) ( cross-platform ) to debug/monitor the outgoing request and incoming response.

If the proxy is running let's say on `127.0.0.1:8080` you can tell the soap client to use the proxy via the options array:

```
private $options = array(
    'proxy_host'   => '127.0.0.1',
    'proxy_port'   => '8080',
    'cache_wsdl'   => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,   // try disabling the wsdl cache for debugging
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,          // check the soap version
    'user_agent'   => 'Batman incoming v2.0',
    // ... more options
);

$this->client = new \SoapClient($this->api, $this->options);
```

Now the SOAPClient will send the requests through the proxy and you can see the incoming/outgoing xml ( or non-xml , hehe ).

Comment: Just downloaded and installed Charles. It seems to have problems when sending https requests. Have you experienced the same problem?

Comment: hm havent used charles for a while in Fiddler you can decrypt https requests. Update: charles has the decrypt SSL option - note that this will lead to a certificate warning as the proxy sends his own certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the soap client class enabled me to see exactly what was being returned.

```
class SoapClientNG extends \SoapClient{

    public function __doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version = SOAP_1_1, $one_way = 0){

        $xml = explode("\r\n", parent::__doRequest($req, $location, $action, $version));


        $response = preg_replace( '/^(\x00\x00\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE\x00\x00|\xFE\xFF|\xFF\xFE|\xEF\xBB\xBF)/', "", $xml[5] );

        return $response;

    }

}
```

Turns out the xml it was receiving contained errors. Deleting the products in Magneto and re-entering them fixed the problem.